# How to generate JSON object from unstructured data in Hadoop MR?

Tags: java, json, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a data set as 
parent,child
------------
a,b
a,c
b,d
b,e
c,f
c,g
g,h
g,i
p,q
p,r
q,s
q,t
that **I want to be convert into JSON object**. I am trying to do but not know proper approach. so I just create a tree structure of the data set that may help to solve it. Can you give me suggestion what to do for achieving this. 
[image]

I am facing problem, how to identify the parent node. if there are two trees comes as given in image. please suggest me how can I do this.

The output of this should be

```
{
    a:{
            b: {d,e},
            c: { g: {h,i}, f }
        },
    p:{     q:{s,t}, r }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd start with finding all roots. This can be done by building tree structure from input pairs using some existing module (I don't know which one...), but this can be done simpler. If you create two sets: one with all parents and the other with all childs, and then subtract parents from childs - you'll get roots.

Then, starting from roots, you can build dictionary and then convert it to JSON (sorry, I am not good at java, so write this in pseudo-code).

```
for r in roots:
    ## init dictionary key with value = dictionary or Null  
    dict[r] = build_tree(r, pairs)
```

So, obviously, **build_tree()** should be recursive update of dictionary, where on each stage you create a new dict with keys that are childs of input parent and values equal to **build_tree()** or **Null** if no more childs can be found.
On the last stage, of course, there should be method to save dictionary as JSON.

Note: the above assumes that you have no circles, but if you have - you need more complex algorithm and make some assumptions on how you, for example, stop recursion and make "some kind of" reference to the beginning of circle.